# Error status=203/EXEC en servicio Prometheus

Tags: centos7

estoy probando Prometheus para monitorear unos servidores en un entorno de prueba e inicialmente segui estos pasos detallados aca y pude lograrlo:

https://www.shellhacks.com/prometheus-monitoring-install-docker-ubuntu-centos/?unapproved=13938&moderation-hash=8274dbc8a2b96cbfeb249520ea46018c#comment-13938

Hoy trate de correr de nuevo el servicio y me arroja el siguiente error:

> prometheus.service - Prometheus monitoring docker container Loaded:
>   loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service; enabled; vendor
>   preset: disabled)
>
> Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since mar 2020-01-21 12:48:20
>   -03; 7s ago
>
> Process: 17071 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose down
>   (code=exited,status=203/EXEC)
>
> Process: 17069 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up (code=exited,
>   status=203/EXEC)
>
> Main PID: 17069 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
>
> ene 21 12:48:19 localhost systemd[1]: prometheus.service: control
>   process exited, code=exited status=203
>          ene 21 12:48:19 localhost systemd[1]: Unit prometheus.service entered    failed state.
>          ene 21 12:48:19 localhost systemd[1]: prometheus.service failed.
>          ene 21 12:48:20 localhost systemd[1]: prometheus.service holdoff time    over, scheduling restart.
>          ene 21 12:48:20 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Prometheus monitoring    docker container.
>          ene 21 12:48:20 localhost systemd[1]: start request repeated too    quickly for prometheus.service
>          ene 21 12:48:20 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Prometheus    monitoring docker container.
>          ene 21 12:48:20 localhost systemd[1]: Unit prometheus.service entered    failed state.
>          ene 21 12:48:20 localhost systemd[1]: prometheus.service failed.

Si tienen alguna sugerencia para solucionar esto, gracias.

Comment: No se si te ayuda, pero aquí explican una solución: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26237

Comment: Que dice el log de journalctl